# Англоязычная версия сайта

Tags: seo

С точки зрения оптимизации для поисковых систем, как лучше делать англоязычную версию сайта?

1. Поддомен en.site.ru
2. Настройки языка в куках (т.е. при смене языка пишем в куки, что выбран английский язык)

Comment: Данный вопрос следует закрыть, потому что он не относится к программированию.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Основное требование чтобы страницы были уникальны. Т.е. по адресу: site.ru не могло открыться 2 разные страницы рус и англ (это как раз в случае с куками).
Можно сделать на поддомене, можно в виде:

site.ru/ рус. главная

site.ru/news/ рус. новости

site.ru/en/ англ. главная

site.ru/en/news/ англ. новости

Answer (score 4):

Куки не стоит использовать - как сказали выше, страницы должны быть уникальны.
[Аналогичное обсуждение](http://forum.searchengines.ru/showthread.php?t=770782&page=2) на сеофоруме.

Comment: Куки можно использовать, в них хранить язык который выбрал пользователь, далее прочитать куку и в зависимости от языка сделать редирект по соотв. url-у.

Comment: Куки как раз нужно использовать, дело в том, что неполные ответы и односложные предложения с заявкой на ответ вводят в заблуждение. То есть куки надо использовать для хранения выбора пользователя. А сами страницы естественно должны быть по разным адресам. При этом куда направлять пользователя - это отдельная логика - если есть сохраненный выбор в куках - отправляем на страницы соответствующего языка, если нет выбора в куках - отправляем на страницы того языка, который определился через функцию GeoIp (если она предусмотрена).

Answer (score 1):

[Курим доки гугла №1](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/182192?hl=ru)
[Курим доки гугла #2](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/189077?hl=ru)
По второй ссылке стоит заметить, что они не рекомендуют использовать динамические параметры для языковой версии, однако используют её сами.
[Курим доки Яндекса](https://yandex.ru/support/webmaster/yandex-indexing/locale-pages.html)

Если выбирать только из вариантов в вопросе, то определенно поддомен. С точки зрения поисковой оптимизации "лучше" правильно сделать разметку hreflang, а где будет располагаться языковая версия (поддомен или подпапка) особой роли не играет. Но также стоит учитывать то, что поддомен является "отдельным сайтом" и ссылки, ведущие на поддомен не передадут никакого веса для основной версии сайта. Хотя я не уверен по поводу именно языкового поддомена, ведь их скорее всего "склеивают" в единый, но как раз [Сергей Кокшаров - Что лучше: поддомен или подпапка?"](https://devaka.ru/webinars/chto-luchshe-dlya-seo-poddomen-ili-podpapka) может помочь вам в определении "лучшего" варианта.