# мультиязычное описание сайта

Tags: php, seo

здравствуйте, вообщем на сайте тэг Description и титул главной станицы выводится в зависимости от языка пользователя, а тот в свою очередь определятся с помощью $_SERVER HTTP Accept Language,так вот у меня такой вопрос, допустим у англичан титул на английском, у русских на русском, а какой титул будет выводится в гугле и яндексе? или как можно сделать чтобы взависимости от языка человека, при выдаче результатов, ему выдавало русскую версию сайта

Comment: думаю, что найдете ответ здесь https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/188883/%D0%90%D0%BD%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%8F%D0%B7%D1%8B%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%B0?rq=1

Answer (score 2):

Никогда и не при каких условиях не размещайте один и тот же контент по одному адресу. Во-первых, в Гугле отобразится только английский язык (или какой там у вас по умолчанию — не помню, передаёт ли гугл Accept-Language). То же касается определений координат по IP — будет адрес сервера гугл-бота. Во-вторых, поисковики не любят такое дело. Поисковики должны видеть то же, что и обычные посетители, иначе это формально нарушение.

Как правильно это сделать — описано в ответах к вопросу [Англоязычная версия сайта](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/188883). В идеале там ещё кое-какую мета-информацию можно указать, но вообще поисковики обычно справляются с анализом сами.

Comment: у меня новостной сайт, с главной лентой. если ты зашел с европы то выводится английский контент, если с россии - русский. на странице с полной новостью, язык статьи не меняется, меняется только язык интерфейса. вообщем грубо говоря как в вк, какой язык выбрал, на такой меняется только системные элементы сайта. но дело в том что мета тэг Description тоже выводится в зависимости от языка, и я не знаю как сделать чтоб в гугле он выводился на руссокм

Comment: @turik97 У вас сам **контент** на каком языке? В общем списке новостей. Фильтруется по языку? Всё в куче? Не понимаю, какая функция у многоязычности на новостном сайте, если только вы не агрегатор. Но и тогда разный контент следует отображать по идее. Если вы хотите русское описание в гугле, то что-то мне подсказывает, что от английского интерфейса пользы ноль. / Могу предложить костыль, не разбираясь с проблемой XY — смотреть User-agent и выдавать русскую версию, если там Googlebot. Для нормального решения нужно смотреть сайт.